# How to check the background color of a UIButton

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

Is there any way to check the background of a UIButton.

```
UIButton *btn = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 50, 300, 100)];
btn.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
[self.view addSubview:btn];
```

Now I want to check whether my button having the backgroundcolor or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use below code to check if your button has background color or not. `isEqual` will match both object are same or not.

```
if ([btn.backgroundColor isEqual:[UIColor colorWithRed:74.0f/255.0f green:165.0f/255.0f blue:155.0f/255.0f alpha:1]])
    NSLog(@"Same color");
else
    NSLog(@"not same");
```

if you change rgb then you will get not same.

Comment: i have set the button backgroundcolor  variantSizeButton.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:216.0f/255.0f green:215.0f/255.0f blue:217.0f/255.0f alpha:1];   after set the color.. nslog (buttonColor colorUIDeviceRGBColorSpace 0.847059 0.843137 0.85098 1)

Comment: @Iphonenew what exactly you want? you want to check that button's background color is set or not? or anything else. if you set this code then you will get `UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 0.290196 0.647059 0.607843 1`

Comment: after set the background color, how to check whether the button background color present ot not.

Comment: @Iphonenew check my answer i wrote all thing when you will get background color is present or not. did you get me what i'm tryin to say?

Comment: if my button color is nil  am getting the  NSLog(@"no bg set") .. can you please check my code.                                      UIButton *btn = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 50, 300, 100)];
btn.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:74.0f/255.0f green:165.0f/255.0f blue:155.0f/255.0f alpha:1];
[self.view addSubview:btn];      and am checking if(btn.backgroundcolor==[UIColor colorWithRed:74.0f/255.0f green:165.0f/255.0f blue:155.0f/255.0f alpha:1]) {//color same}  else{//no same color}

Comment: @Iphonenew for that you should use `isEqual` property. check my edited answer. and you should add in your question that **check same background color**

Answer (score 4):

I think you're asking this question because you don't see any result / don't see any button.
You're initing the button the wrong way, you're supposed to do it as follows:

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[button setFrame:CGRectMake(50, 50, 300, 100)];
[button setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
NSLog(@"%@", button.backgroundColor);
[self.view addSubview:button];
```

I also have added a `NSLog()` so you can check the background color.

`2014-11-20 13:35:14.438 App[19290:3475731] UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 0 0 1 1`

You will get a UIDeviceRGBColorSpace and a few numbers, which stand for:

**RED GREEN BLUE ALPHA**

Comment: am getting the UIDeviceRGBColorSpace but that color is not matching with this UIDeviceRGBColorSpace...

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
if (btn.backgroundColor == [UIColor blueColor]) {
   NSLog(@"My button background is blue");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to get only background color of UIButton

```
UIColor* buttonColor = button.backgroundColor;
```

try this and let me know.

Answer (score 0):

If I get your question right you just want to get the background color of a button ?

```
UIButton *btn = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 50, 300, 100)];
btn.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];

if (btn.backgroundColor==nil)
NSLog(@"no bg set");
else
NSLog(@"%@",btn.backgroundColor);
```

Comment: OMG what is this its Wrong

Comment: you should assign colour first :). otherwise it will give you nil. and now no need `UIColor* buttonColor = btn.backgroundColor;` because you are not using that.

Comment: Is it ok now? I was actually assuming that bg color of uibutton has already set

Comment: now you dont need `UIColor* buttonColor = btn.backgroundColor;` because you are not using it.

Answer (score 0):

```
UILabel *lblHeader = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 15, self.view.frame.size.width-10, 44)];
lblHeader.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor]; 
lblHeader.text = [arrImages objectAtIndex:indexPath];
lblHeader.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
NSLog(@"color of lable is %@",lblHeader.backgroundColor);
[self.view addSubview:lblHeader];
```

Then output of Your Background Color You can see  in Your console:-

2014-11-20 18:51:29.067 iSeventhAssignment[2500:103851] **color of lable is UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 0 0 1 1**